# How to remove invalid byte sequence?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, html-parsing

I'm scraping html and running into "invalid byte sequence errors". I followed some advice in a another post and inserted the following two lines of code:

```
doc_scores.encode!('UTF-16', :undef => :replace, :invalid => :replace, :replace => "")
doc_scores.encode!('UTF-8')
```

This helped reduce the errors dramatically, however, I'm still geting the following exception about 10-20% of the time (in other words about 1 out of every 5 html scans):

```
Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xEA 0x20 0x20 0x22
```

It's always this same sequence of bytes. Any ideas how I should go about removing these?

Comment: Is there any chance it is starting out thinking it is UTF-16?  If so, the firs line will not do anything.  What are you using the string for after these two lines that causes the actual exception?

Comment: @singpolyma I've checked that it is encoded as UTF-8, so I don't think that's the issue. I am using the string to scan for a few particular lines of javascript.

Comment: So, whenyou use `=~` on `doc_scores`, that produces the exception?  Even after doing this round-trip re-encode?

Comment: I think the exception might be the character ê and maybe similar ones with accents. I'm actually scraping data from ESPN. Here is the link to a page that has an invalid byte sequence (http://scores.espn.go.com/nba/scoreboard?date=20031018), and I did some hex snooping and found EA is ê, which occurs in Nenê Hilario. The question is how to get around this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  See http://pastie.org/5086220  Please provide details on what the actual code throwing the exception is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my problem. It turns out it was the encoding of the XML document that I was scraping that was a problem. To fix this, I am now making the encoding option explicit:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(open(url),nil,'ISO-8859-1')
```

Before I just had:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(open(url))
```

Hope this helps someone.